# Bootstrap div disappears on mobile after reaching x-repeat of background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm honestly stumped with this bug. My website is working perfectly fine on my laptop browser (at least it seems so). But when I switch to my phone it breaks.

```js
(function animateBG() {
  $('#logo-fallback').animate({
    backgroundPosition: '-=1'
  }, 12, animateBG);
})();
```

```css
#logo-fallback {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B3gO.png);
  background-size: auto 130px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="clearfix" id="logo-fallback"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-centered">
          <h4 class="text-muted">Sorry, nothing here.</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

container div, which contains a div with an id of #logo-fallback. #logo-fallback has a background image that repeats on the x-axis, and the x-position of the image decreases by 1 continuously using a jQuery animation to create a 'scrolling' effect.

This seems to work flawlessly on my computer's browser but when I switch to my mobile the image disappears once it has reached the start of the first repeat and reappears a few moments later.

Also, the image seems to move slower on my mobile...

I hope I made some sense out of my situation.

Kindest Regards,

Comment: sees to work in the dev tools on mobile

Comment: Those two effects normally are a result of the processor of your phone.

Comment: I've been trying it on different phone's and browser's and at the moment the bug only seems to occur on the Google Chrome app, specifically on Samsung devices.

Comment: @ChrisHappy I've tested it on the new Samsung Galaxy S8 and the bug still occurs.

Comment: To add, if I toggle the setting to request the desktop site it works.